# options for comparing datamodels between 2 databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to identify the datamodel differences between 2 databases: DB1 and DB2. I need a way to identify missing/extra database objects and naming differences. Is there a sproc or free tool that you can recommend for this purpose?

Comment: [SQL Server Data Tools has a good schema compare feature.](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/features/ssdt/)

Comment: ^^^ SSDT would be your free choice, and yes it works great.  Another tool I've had success with is RedGate SQL Compare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compare between two database schema, you can use visual studio 2015. Please follow the following steps.

1. Open the visual studio 2015 IDE.
2. Go to the tools menu according to the following image.

[image]

3. Then select source and destination database as per following image.

[image]

4. Then compare button and see the changes between source and destination database according to the following image.

[image]

5. After clicking update button, your destination database schema will be changed as per source database.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, instead of hitting the Update button, you could hit the Script button right next to it, which will generate, but not run, the code to make the changes. Then you can tweak it, or run it at a later time.

Comment: @EricBrandt, Exactly you can also generate script. and this script will do same work as update button will do. Thanks.