# Check the names of Tables/Views/Procs and compare with those from a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently in the process of moving tables, views, and stored procedures from one database in SQL Server to another database on the same server.  A couple weeks ago, I had already started manually moving some of these procdures, and I am unsure of which ones I have moved so far. I want to write a query that compares the tables I have already moved to database 2 to the ones in database 1, and lists the stuff in database 1 I have not moved yet. I guess I am confused as to where to start, as I don't have much experience in using the system tables.

Comment: Are you moving all of them or some of them from db A to db B?

Comment: Look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.

Comment: You can check them in sys.tables and sys.objects

Comment: you may get help from this answer 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/49413552/3436184'

Comment: Yeah, I'm moving all views/procs, but some of them are already moved, so I only need to see the ones in A that havent been moved yet

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to disregard which you already did, script them all out using the SSMS Generate Scripts task, and do a DROP/CREATE or check for existence just to be sure.

1. Open SSMS
2. Open the object explorer, connect to your instance,
   and open the Databases folder
3. Right click on the database that
   has the object you want to move over and click Tasks, then click
   Generate Scripts
4. Click the Select specific database objects radio button and select all the tables/procs/etc you want to move over. Click Next
5. Click Advanced, change Script Drop and CREATE to SCRIPT DROP AND CREATE (or change Check for object existence to TRUE), then change Types of Data to Script to Schema and Data
6. Click Save to File radio button and script it all out

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should work.

```
select 
    name
    ,type_desc
from 
    CurrentDatabase.sys.objects
where
    is_ms_shipped <> 1
    and type_desc in ('VIEW','SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE','USER_TABLE') --add in trigers, TVF, etc that you may want...

except 

select 
    name
    ,type_desc
from 
    YourNewDatabase.sys.objects
where
    is_ms_shipped <> 1
    and type_desc in ('VIEW','SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE','USER_TABLE') --add in trigers, TVF, etc that you may want...
```